# Can I initialize an array to a range of values?

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, range

Using ColdFusion, is there any simple way to initialize an array with a range of numbers?

I know that I can loop:

```
testArray = [];
    for(i=345;i<645;i++){
        ArrayAppend(testArray,i);
    }
```

Is there any implicit way to initialize an array and populate it with a range of numbers?

Comment: If any way you are going to use range of values, why do you need to store the values in an array?

Comment: @Pankaj - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740376/how-can-i-split-a-range-of-values-among-a-pool-of-threads :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the only *built in* method to init an array with data is arrayset, and it only lets you use *one* value, not a range. So I'd say the answer is no. Maybe you can get around it by hitting the Java level, but there isn't anything as a 'built in' CF func for this.

Answer (score 2):

Ray already answered, but just for fun:

```
<cfscript>

testArray  = createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.lang.math.IntRange")
                 .init(345,645).toArray();

writeOutput(testArray[1] & "<br>");

writeOutput(arrayLen(testArray) & "<br>");

writeOutput(arrayToList(testArray));

</cfscript>
```

RUN ME: http://www.trycf.com/scratch-pad/pastebin?id=gCG7EASp

Notice that `testArray` is really an `int[]` array.  While CF is smart enough to work with it but certain array function like `arrayAppend()` that expects `java.util.Vector` will fail.

I'm surprised no `javacast("int", 345)` is needed.