# How can I split a range of values among a "pool" of threads?

Tags: arrays, multithreading, coldfusion

I have some code that processes around 30,000 records. The basic outline is like this:

```
startRecordID = 2345;
endRecordID = 32345;
for(recordID=startRecordID; recordID <= endRecordID; recordID++){
    // process record...
}
```

Now, this processing takes a long time, and I'd like to have a thread pool of 15 threads and give each thread a list of recordIDs to process, and then join them all at the end.

In the past I accomplished this with code that looked something like this, where `recordLists` was an array of sub-arrays each containing 1/15 of the records to be processed:

```
<cfset numThreads = 15 />
<!--- keep a running list of threads so we can join them all at the end --->
<cfset threadlist = "" />
<cfloop from="1" to="#numThreads#" index="threadNum">
    <cfset threadName = "recordProcessing_#threadNum#" />
    <cfset threadlist = listAppend(threadlist, threadName) />
    <cfthread action="run" name="#threadName#" recordList="#recordList[threadNum]#">
        <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(recordList)#" index="recordIndex">
            <cfset recordID = recordList[recordIndex] />
            ... process recordID ...
        </cfloop>
    </cfthread> 
</cfloop>
<!--- Join all threads before continuing --->
<cfthread action="join" name="#threadlist#" timeout="4000"/>
```

This worked well (although I would also convert this old code to cfscript :) ), but to create the recordLists array of sub-arrays is not so simple... The way I can think of to do it would be to loop through the numbers from startRecordID-endRecordID, add each  to an array, then run an ArrayDivide function (that we have already defined in our codebase) on it to split it into numThreads (in this case 15) equal sub-arrays. Considering that I have the start of the range, the end of the range, and the number of threads I want to divide it among, isn't there a simpler way to break it up and assign it to the threads?

Comment: just wondering.. why 15 threads?  Heavy I/O?  How many cores do you have access to?

Comment: I suggest using your existing loop.

Comment: @DanBracuk - how? can you explain how I can incorporate thread-pooling into that loop?

Comment: If you already have an array, why loop through it again? There are no built in functions, but since an array is a java `List`, a simple [`yourArray.subList(startIndex, endIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) would do the trick. NB: Since it is a java method, indexes start at zero and the endIndex is *exclusive*.

Comment: @Leigh - I was looking for something like that... I'll try it out

Comment: I posted an example below. (Too long for comments).

Answer (score 3):

(From comments ..)

If you already have an array, why loop through it again? There are no built in functions, but since an array is a java `List`, a simple [`yourArray.subList(startIndex, endIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) would do the trick. Obviously add some error handling in case the number of records is less than the number of processing threads.

**NB:** Since it is a java method, indexes start at zero (0) and the `endIndex` is *exclusive*.  Also, the result is *like* a CF array in most respects. However, it is immutable ie cannot be modified.

```
<cfscript>
    // calculate how many records to process in each batch
    numOfIterations = 15;
    totalRecords = arrayLen(recordsArray);
    batchSize = ceiling(totalRecords/numOfIterations);


    for (t=0; t < numOfIterations; t++) {
        // calculate sub array positions
        startAt = t * batchSize;
        endAt   = Min(startAt+batchSize, totalRecords);

        // get next batch of records
        subArray = recordsArray.subList(startAt, endAt);

        // kick off a thread and do whatever you want with the array ...
        WriteOutput("<br>Batch ["& t &"] startAt="& startAt &" endAt="& endAt); 
    }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: I'm working on tweaking this, mostly because I don't actually have a `recordsArray` - I just have a range of IDs. The answer is still proving helpful. I'll update when I get it working.

Comment: (Edit) I was going off the example above which used `ArrayLen(recordList)`. What is your "range" object - if not an array?

Comment: That example was code from a previous implementation of threading when I had an array of sub-arrays, as explained in the post. The only code I had currently was the first code loop, in which I had a startRecordID and an endRecordID and needed to figure out how to equally distribute the range between them to the threads. Your answer pointed me in the right direction, and I think I may have some working code... still testing

Comment: I did get it to work, with modified code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good to hear. If you think it would be helpful, feel free to post it as an answer. I only posted the above because it was too long for comments.